# Webpage content disappear when using useNavigate from react-router-dom in React

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-router

I want to use a button on which when I click redirects me to another page.
When I try useNavigate, the page content simply disappear.

My actual code is lengthy, but I got a code from the internet that is similar to the part I'm currently stuck at. Here is the code:

```
import React from 'react';
import {Routes, Route, useNavigate} from 'react-router-dom';

function App() {

  const navigate = useNavigate();

  const navigateToContacts = () => {
    navigate('/contacts');
  };

  const navigateHome = () => {
    navigate('/');
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <div>
        <button onClick={navigateHome}>Home</button>
        <hr />
        <button onClick={navigateToContacts}>Contacts</button>

        <Routes>
          <Route path="/contacts" element={<Contacts />} />
          <Route path="/" element={<Home />} />
        </Routes>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

function Home() {
  return <h2>Home</h2>;
}

function Contacts() {
  return <h2>Contacts</h2>;
}

export default App;
```

Please note that I do not have any warnings or errors showing in the console. I wonder why nothing shows on the webpage...

Comment: Ensure `App` is wrapped inside [`BrowserRouter`](https://reactrouter.com/en/main/router-components/browser-router).

Comment: I see no overt issues with ***this*** code snippet. Think you could create a ***running*** [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/) demo that reproduces this issue that we could inspect live?

Comment: @yousoumar I'm 100% certain if OP was missing rendering the router that there'd be some invariant errors logged to the console. OFC, the OP could have some odd console settings that is hiding these. I know I've done that once or twice when dealing with some noisy app logs.